# How to restrict wamp server to display blank pages after completing a php action?

Tags: php, wamp, action

I'm using Wamp in windows 10 pro.
earlier I used to program php in an android device with PAW WEB SERVER app.
this app would avoid showing any blank pages.
for example if I want to load a file named 'test.html' through this server app in android and this file (i.e 'test.html') has got no content in it and its size is 0 bytes than the server would ignore that file and would remain on the same page that had been opened before.
so I need such thing in WAMP server 
can you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such behavior of a http server actually is a pretty bold thing to do and kind of violates how web servers should  work. A standard server has no concept of "remaining", since http is a stateless protocol. And it certainly should  return an empty reply if that is what its internal resources provide.

Even if you really need such a strange behavior on your server side component and want to rely on a standard http server and you implement your own logic, for example in form of a simple php script which does exactly what you ask, even then you would not get the desired result. Since the server has no means to "nor reply". It has to either send a normal response (which might be empty) or an error status. Such error status however will cause every standard compliant http client to visualize the issue. You'd have to use a non standard compliant http client, again implementing your own logic.

An alternative is to simply do the http request from client to server in form of an ajax request, so in background. That allows to decide on client side what to actually do with the received response. You can evaluate any potential http status indicator and "ignore" that reply, so *not* replace the previously loaded view.

Comment: Do you have any other alternative with the settings of the server program?

Comment: As said this is not a question of server side settings. It is more a question of how the client side reacts on certain responses it receives from the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I found something.
not a perfect alternative but can solve my problem.
I wanted this feature for php executions.
what I did is just added a javascript of getting back to the previous page i.e
"history.back();" in the php file.

Comment: Sure possible, but ugly. since the loaded page is discarded and then reloaded. What for? Why didn't you implement the ajax strategy I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: I suggest you take a closer look at that client side app you use (it is not clear to me what that actually is). How it reacts to certain http status values in the response from the server, that should be documented. Regardless of the size of the result I could imagine that a http status 204 or 304 makes sense and could be interpreted by a client to stay on the previously loaded page.

Comment: can you please illustrate an example for same. suppose I have a form which is assigned with the action "test.php"

Comment: No example required. You know what an AJAX request is? If no, there are endless examples you can look at. So instead of relying on the html submit action you submit the form yourself by means of client side javascript. You receive back the response from the server and can, again in javascript on the client side, decide what to do: to replace the loaded page or to leave it.

Comment: I'm getting you now I think. You mean I should store data of the form in server with an AJAX request than process that data in server with server side PHP than get the result back with an AJAX request in HTML page. right?

Comment: Nearly correct. But all is done in one single request. The AJAX request sends whatever data the form contains to the php script which processes the data and sends a response, data or just a status value. That response is all you need. So it is only a single request, not two as you sketched.

Comment: ohhh I got you Thank you very much